# Differences between Magento 1 and Magento 2 REST API?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, api, rest-api

What's the difference between endpoints and integrations?

My main question is for basic things like **products**, **orders** and **customers**, but also like an overview.

Comment: Have you got any reply for your question?

Comment: Not yet @AlexPostushnoy

Answer (score 1):

The docs on Magento 2 Web APIs

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/introduction.html

The Docs on Magento 1 Web APIs

- https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/get-started/bk-get-started-api.html

Some differences that stand out:

- Extended Overall capabilities out of the box. Magento 2 offering more. e.g. M1 offers order retrieval while M2 offers Web APIs functionalities for the whole complete order flow
- Url Structure and the way urls are built (see docs)
- M2 offers the posibility to mention the store area, M1 does not **(needs check for M1 part)**
- M1 implements 3 legged authorization while M2 implements 2 legged authoriation (see docs)